# Twilio SoftClient TimeOut Issue

Tags: twilio

I have successfully create the connection between Twilio soft client and Twilio. But the connection got disconnected after 15 sec automatically.

Please let me know what configuration is needed to increase the time out.

Approach Use - Java / Browser Goggle Chrome

Thanks,
arindam

Comment: Can you run the client in [debug mode](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#setup) and share the logs so that we can see what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the following Client QuickStart:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/client/incoming-calls

As Phil mentioned, it would be helpful if you could ensure that you are [setup in debug mode](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#setup) to share some logs regarding your issue.

However, the issue you describe is often attributed to network issues. You can read more about [Twilio Client's network connectivity requirements here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/what-are-twilio-clients-network-connectivity-requirements).

Please let me know if I can offer further assistance.